# PHP MYSQL Структура пользовательского чата

Tags: php, mysql, chat

Здравствуйте, планирую сделать на сайте пользовательский чат. То есть не общий чат, а между конкретными пользователями, два человека.

Я хотел бы узнать, правильную ли структуру бд я спроектировал.

Есть таблица `rooms`, в ней поля `id`, `userid1`, `userid2`, `lastupdate`

Далее идёт таблица `messages`, в ней поля `id`, `roomid`, `message`, `timestamp`

Далее

При отправке сообщения, мы проверяем есть ли комната где `userid1 = SESSION id`, и `userid2` = `id` пользователя которому адресовано сообщение. Или же проверяем наоборот, где `userid1` = `id` адресату, а `userid2` = `SESSION id`. Так как порядок может быть разным, в зависимости от того кто первый начал диалог.

Если комнаты нет, мы её создаем, а затем отправляем в неё сообщение.

Затем при заходе в чат, мы запрашиваем из БД комнату, где участник1, и участник 2, это наш SESSION пользователь, и адресат.

Comment: Нету идентификатора кому какое сообщение принадлежит и/или кому адресовано.

Comment: поиск по user1 и user2 не особо удобен, т.к. надо проверять два варианта. можно формировать один составной идентификатор, где допустим они отсортированы по возрастанию.

Comment: Использовать session в качестве пользователя выглядит криво. что если сессия прервется, пользователь больше не сможет вернуться к своим разговорам ?

Comment: @Mike да, действительно.

Comment: @Mike мне кажется там все же имеется в виду, id авторизованого пользователя, который хранится в сессии, а не сам ид сессии, т.е. `$_SESSION['id']`

Comment: @teran возможно. что то я не тот свой коммент потер, потрите предложения объединения, что ли :)

Comment: на самом деле, искать все чаты пользователя, по объединенному id не так сложно, если составноый вида `id1-id2`, то искать можно по `cId like 'id1-%' or cId like '%-id1'` , только это прилично менее эффективно будет.

Comment: @teran в любом случае криво. все таки я подозреваю, что таблица пользователей должна быть, тогда user1/2 должны быть ключами по хорошему. И кстати на больше-меньше можно и при вставке в 2 колонки разделить