# Правильная скрутрура БД для чата

Tags: php, mysql

Реализовую что то вроде телеграм. 
Сейчас у меня две таблици. Сообщения и Диалоги. При каждой отправке сообщения проверяеться есть ли такой диалог(если нет, создаеться). Но мне кажеться это не самым оптимальныи решением.
Вопрос. Какой должна быть правильная и оптимальная структура таблиц MySql и логика?

Comment: А диалоги зачем, что в них храниться ?

Comment: вот с коллегой помозгуйте вместе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/772033/223826

Answer (score 0):

Сам столкнулся с такой же задачей пару дней назад, я считаю что это - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43557977/need-database-structure-for-private-group-and-public-chat-mysql не плохой вариант, использовал данную структуру для своих чатов между пользователями.